# Oneboxing Github Repos

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox, github

In chat, there have been several times that we have passed around links to Github repos, to access others' code and resources. Could theses be oneboxed, possibly just including the person's username, the repo title, and tpart of the gist?

Comment: What is oneboxing??????

Comment: @ChristmasUnicorn http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/onebox

Comment: @ChristmasUnicorn [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/n4mVq.png) - you type link to a question or answer for example, and it's "oneboxed" in chat.

Comment: There was oneboxing but it's broken due to github blocking it.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that. Do you think SE could "Talk" to them?